# I have created a combobox with checkboxes But I am unable to catch the event when a checkbox is checked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

The code to generate a checkable combobox is as follows:

```
def check_able_combox(combo, options, length):

    model = QStandardItemModel(length, 1) # 4 rows, 1 col
    for i,area in enumerate(options):
        item = QStandardItem(area)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        model.setItem(i, 0, item)
    combo.setModel(model)
    return combo
```

And I am using the above function in this manner:

```
self.checkable_combobox_usecases =check_able_combox(self.usecaseTypeCombobox, usecase_type, len(usecase_type))
```

where, `self.usecaseTypeCombobox` is a regular combobox that I have created and
       `usecase_type` 
is a list `["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]`

So, I do get a combobox with checkboxes with this code. But I also want to capture the text of the checkbox which I am checking. Could someone please guide me how to capture this event?

I tried with 
`self.checkable_combobox_usecases.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.get_UsecaseType)` 
--> but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currentIndexChanged signal is only emitted when an item is selected, not when an item is checked so that signal will not work.

Considering the above is to use the itemChanged signal of the model that is emitted when some information changes, in this case that signal would be emitted when the checkbox status changes but also when any other information associated with the roles changes, in order to discriminate we must remember the status previous and check if it has changed.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QMainWindow

LastStateRole = Qt.UserRole + 1000


def check_able_combox(combo, options):
    model = QStandardItemModel(len(options), 1)
    for i, area in enumerate(options):
        item = QStandardItem(area)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        model.setItem(i, 0, item)
    combo.setModel(model)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.usecaseTypeCombobox = QComboBox()

        usecase_type = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
        check_able_combox(self.usecaseTypeCombobox, usecase_type)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.usecaseTypeCombobox)

        self.usecaseTypeCombobox.model().itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)

    @pyqtSlot("QStandardItem*")
    def on_itemChanged(self, item):
        last_state = item.data(LastStateRole)
        current_state = item.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
        # verify that the modified data is related to the Qt::CheckStateRole role
        if last_state != current_state:
            # save last state
            item.model().blockSignals(True)
            item.setData(current_state, LastStateRole)
            item.model().blockSignals(False)

            print(current_state, item.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It solved my blocker.

I have another question to you.  I was also trying to send `item.text()` to a QTableWidget everytime a checkbox is checked. I was able to  add new rows to the table everytime the checkbox was checked, however I was not able to display the text of the checkbox in the QTableWidget row. Could you help me please?

Comment: @user1430431 If you have another problem then write another post, the comments only serve to discuss the current Q/A

Comment: Is it also possible to get the index of the checked checkbox?

Comment: @user1430431 I think you want to use it for your other question, I have proposed an answer that makes it easier

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a slot to a signal, the slot function signature should match with signal.

Here the signature of signal, based on documentation is

```
PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox.currentIndexChanged(index)
```

you need to define a function, that takes index as input parameter.

So something like this (rough code):

```
def selectionchange(self,i):
      print "Current index",i,"selection changed ",self.checkable_combobox_usecases.currentText()
```

and while connecting try like something below in `check_able_combox` function

```
combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
```